# Is it possible to listen to incoming SMS and forward them in Windows Phone 8 API?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to in my app to be able to forward smses from my windows phone 8 app, given the user have checked a checkbox.

I cant find anything on the let showing how to do this.

Anyone know if its possible, and if so how.

Comment: SMS interception APIs are only available to OEMs

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

The only way you have for interacting with SMS's is through the `SmsComposerTask`which only let's you pop-up an interface for sending SMS (with possible predefined values for the recipient and the message).

There is no way to intercept or listen for SMS's nor to send SMS's without the user initiating it

Comment: sad panda! Friend made Android app that we wanted to port to Phone Alos. Guess that idea stops here.